# Get every combination of multiple arrays that can have multiple options

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I know a similar question has been asked in the past but this one is a bit different.  I'm looking to get every variation possible including multiple options from a single array so.  I'm really struggling with this and I greatly appreciate any help in it.

```
$arrayA = array("1","2","3");
$arrayB = array("A","B");
```

Results should be

```
1
2
3
12
13
121
123
1A
1B
1C
1A
12A
```

etc..

so the same value can't be repeated twice but can include others from the same array.  The desired output is in the form of an array where it's easy to see what the pulled elements are.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: I don't even know how to begin this one... I was able to create a single superset from one array and I'm able to get variations from multiple arrays where it picks 1 from each but I have no clue how to get the two together...